# Getting POST parameter from Request

Tags: jquery, form-data

I'm using Symfony4 and I'm trying to get POST parameter from Request. Using:

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$email = $request->request->get('email');
```

Give me null but if I do:

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
var_dump($request->request->all());
```

I can see that email parameter is setted and has some value.
My question is: How can i get that parameter value?

I post a piece of my code here:

```
/**
 * @Route("/prenota/appuntamento/salva", name="app_habiter_calendario_save", methods={"POST"})
     */
  public function salvaPrenotazione(ValidatorInterface $validator){
     $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
     $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
     $prenotazioni = new Prenotazioni();
     $clienti = new Clienti();

     $email = $request->request->get('email');
     [...]
}
```

Screenshot of

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
var_dump($request->request->all());
```

[image]

The request are made by AJAX with this function. Might be this the reason of the problem?:

```
function sendMailAjax(form, method, url, outputElement){
  let formData = new FormData(form);
  $.ajax({
    method: method,
    url: url,
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
  }).done(function (result) {
    if(result.message === true) {
      outputElement.css('color', 'green');
      outputElement.text('Inviato');
    }else {
      outputElement.css('color', 'red');
      outputElement.text('Errore');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `var_dump($request->request->all())` so we also can see what it contains.

Comment: Reading [this article](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/13585) might give some insights.

Comment: Can you also include the HTML code that contains the form please?

Comment: "form" parameter that i passed is actually the selector of my form element,  let formData = new FormData(form); get all my form data. This is the reason why i do that

Comment: I want to see the actual HTML `<form>` tag

Comment: Instead of `let formData = new FormData(form);` Try `form_data = $("form").serialize();` Then check the `var_dump()`

Comment: I suspect the `FormData` call is the issue. If you look at your current `var_dump` output, the entire form appears as one giant value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AJAX call, change

```
let formData = new FormData(form);
  $.ajax({
    method: method,
    url: url,
    data: formData,
```

to:

```
let formData = $("form").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    method: method,
    url: url,
    data: formData,
```